# Python: errno2 No such file or directory

Tags: python

I am learning Python from "Learn Python the Hard Way" and searched up quite a bit on it with no solutions as of yet.

I configured the path for python to work on the command prompt. But whenever I type in

"python ex1.py"

it comes up with an error: Errno2 No such file or directory!

The code is a simple print code, nothing much there. But I do not know why it's showing this! I have all these exercises in the python directory

C:\python27\projects\ex1.py

Comment: Try with the full path `C:\python27\projects\ex1.py` or assure that you are in the correct working directory.

Answer (score 0):

In general, windows defaults to the user directory in the command prompt. Saying "python ex1.py" is trying to find ex1.py in the C:\User\Username directory. Try moving your python script there or moving to the python projects folder using cd. Either way should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it usually works when I do a " python C:\python27\projects\ex1.py" command, but I don't want to use all of that. How do I go on about using "cd" to move move to the python projects folder? Sorry i'm a beginner as you can see!

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to use the path, just save your files in your user default directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the right directory when you type `python ex1.py`? In your case, does it say `C:\python27\projects\` in the command prompt before you type the command in? It looks for the file in the current directory, not in any directory unless you specify it. (example: you could type `python C:\python27\projects\ex1.py` in this instance)

To switch directories, use the [`cd` command](http://www.computerhope.com/cdhlp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

im a newbie too for a little googling i found an easy way,it just.. you should change your cmd directory to where the file is.. by typing cd
in your cmd type it with space and drag your file to cmd it will change the cmd directory automaticly to the address of that file and now you can put python helloworld.py to cmd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).